# Azure hosting Playwright Tests

Tags: playwright

What is the suggestion to run Microsoft Playwright Tests periodically on Azure? I mean, not only as part of a Release Pipeline after a deployment, else running every 10 minutes? Using an Azure Function maybe? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In general ,instead of running on any fixed interval (like 10 minutes) I would suggest
running of any suite , **triggered by each commit.**

Every time dev push a commit (usually in a branch, but that does include master) the tests are triggered to run.

You may setup suites on multiple level with varying complexity and coverage like smoke, integration or full regression based on your individual project requirements.